# Why did NASA want the Z-2 prototype spacesuit need to mimic the appearance of sportswear?

Tags: mars, nasa, spacesuits

NASA has been considering a new type of space suit, the [Z2 Spacesuit](https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/nmss-z2), "in order to protect NASA astronauts embarking on a new class of mission, NASA has to build a new class of space suit. Far off explorers traversing the surface of the red planet will be exposed to an environment unlike what current spacewalking suits are equipped to deal with."

In this NASA page, [Z-2 prototype suit cover layer designs](https://www.nasa.gov/content/z-2-prototype-suit-cover-layer-designs-0/#.Xf7LtC3MxTY),

[image: ing]it talks about the suit using "a bright color scheme to mimic the appearance of sportswear and the emerging world of wearable technologies."

Was there any explanation why mimicking sportswear is important for this suit beyond it seeming stylish?

Comment: It is probably not important for the functioning of the suit, that would work regardless of the colour. Somebody thought this would be more pleasing to the eye and look posh when streaming future space missions. Leaving it to the public to vote for a design imo hints in that direction ...

Comment: @ebv That may well be, but it makes me wonder why fitting in the "trends is society" is important for the suit.  I would've guessed having astronauts stand out as being distinct would give them, dare I say, a more heroic stature.